# How to transmit a 32 bits word with SPI on a stm32 to a GPS receiver chip (MAX2769C)

Tags: stm32, spi, hal

I am trying to configure a GPS receiver chip (MAX2769C) with an stm32f446re MCU using SPI in half duplex master mode. The chip is expecting a 32 bit word (4 bits address and 28 bits data). This is on page 21 of the [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX2769C.pdf).

My first question is how can I transmit a 32 bits word when the maximum bits format that cubemx allows is 16 bits transfer.
My second problem is that, I have to generate a clock of exactly 16,384 MHZ to feed the MAX2769C chip (this is not the data clock SCK of the SPI). So I selected MCO1 in cubemx and played around with clock configuration until I got 16.384 MHZ. How is this going to affect the SPI speed?
I have tried using hal_spi_transmit using an unint8_t array of 4 bytes but this doesn't work.

```
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_Delay(10);

  //Set IF centre frequency to 3.9 MHz

  //SPI read data
  //1. Put CS low - Activate
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  //2. Write data (0A2919A3) to slave
  spiTX1Data[0] = 0x0A; // Transmit register address 0000
  spiTX1Data[1] =0x29; // Set FCEN  to 001101 & FBW to 00 in configuration 1
  spiTX1Data[2] =0x19; 
  spiTX1Data[3] =0xA3; 



  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, spiTX3Data, 4, 10);


  //3. Read
  HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi2, &spiTX1Data[3], 4, 10);


  //Bring CS high - Deactivate
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_SET);
```

It's my first time asking a question on this platform. Thank you in advance!

Comment: SPI is a serial protocol, it means it sends data bit per bit. it can send as many bits as you want. Now, the interface of SPI (the registers of STM32) provides different ways to send 32 bits: either by writing directly 32 bits to the SPI data register (obvisouly the easiest way) or by writing 4 bytes or 2x16 bits. You only need to configure the SPI properly (number of bytes to send, NSS management and other parameters).

Comment: About the clock: the Master (I assume your STM32) is providing the clock to the Slave. You are saying that this slave is supporting only one frequency. This frequency is exactly the "speed" of the SPI communication.

Comment: Now when you says "it doesn't work". The SPI setup can be tricky. You have to setup properly the GPIOs (alternate function, speed, etc...), the SPI peripheral (communication mode, size of data, size of transfer, etc...). Then, you may use a logic analyser to check what your STM32 is really sending ot not.

Comment: Thank you @GuillaumePetitjean for the clear explanation.

Comment: Do you mind showing me how to write directly 32 bits to the SPI data register?

Comment: What do you see on the scope?

Comment: @dannymsolo nothing particular, something like `SPI_DR = (uint32_t)value`  (didn't check the register name). but as I said, this is not the difficult part, check carefully the setup of SPI

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Thank you, I really appreciate your assistance.